# git: Cannot merge a file due to unknown .gitignore rules

Tags: git, version-control, merge, dvcs, gitignore

I was merging a file but upon finishing the 3-way merge, I saw this:

```
Normal merge conflict for 'myfile.ext':
  {local}: modified file
  {remote}: modified file
Hit return to start merge resolution tool (araxis): 
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
Installers
Use -f if you really want to add them.
fatal: no files added
```

And `git status` gives:

```
Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#   (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
#
#       both modified:      myfile.ext
```

I tried to find the .gitignore but it was fruitless.
Is there a way to force merge before I fix the problem .gitignore file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to force a merge to a particular branch [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594344/git-merge-force)

Regarding the gitignore file, what does the following give?

```
git config --get core.excludesfile
```

Is `Installers` in there?

Comment: Thanks Mark. I looked at your link and I want something different from  accept-ours or -theirs. I do need to explicitly resolve conflicts and then check in. So I'd really have to run git mergetool on that file. You tip about core.excludesfile is very helpful and I fixed the ignore rule. Thanks!