# Can I have git create a commit that makes a branch look exactly like another?

Tags: git

I have two branches, A and B. Those have deviated quite a bit over time, and trying to merge A and B results in a ton of conflicts. I don't actually need many things from B, and those things need to be in different places now.

So I'd like to make B look exactly like A - not a merge, no extra files, no file changes, literally like I'd just called `git checkout -b B` while in A.

However, I don't want to lose B's history. What I want is for git to create a differential commit that shows what needed to change in B to make it look exactly like A.

Is there such a command?

Comment: This question is slightly different than the one that is marked as a duplicate - in that question the author is willing to discard the history, and so git-reset is a valid option. Here, history needs to be preserved. 

The answer is `git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/<your branch B>` from branch A and then a simple Add and Commit.

If this question removes the duplicate marking then I can post this as answer and elaborate a bit more.

Comment: Looks like the other question wants to do a partial merge too, further to my point.

Answer (score 0):

When you do a merge you don't lose the history provided you didn't do any fast forward. You could just branch from b, merge a into it

Comment: The OP is asking something different - how do they do a merge so that `B` looks *exactly* like `A`?

Comment: Indeed. `git merge A` while in B results in a ton of merge conflicts that aren't worth resolving since it's mostly cheese moving. So I want to make B look exactly like A, and then just manually reapply the actual changes, but I need to keep B's history. (Otherwise I'd just delete B and branch off of A again). Looking at [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47704784/91) right now.